# VScode kivy wont use the .Kv file

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code, kivy

I'm using VScode and Kivy. I cant seem to get Kivy to read the .kv file. I have both the .py file and .kv files set up, but when I run the program all I get is an empty box.
.kv file:

```
#kivy 2.0.0
<layout>
    Label:
        text: 'text here'
```

.py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class layout(GridLayout):
pass

class theApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theApp().run()
```

I can get it all to work if I write it in just the .py file but nothing works from the .kv file.
If I under stand right the box should say "text here".

Comment: What is the name of your `.kv` file?

Comment: in this example it would be:  the.kv